# django. GenericForeginKey null when content_type and object_id is set

Tags: django, generic-foreign-key

I have the following fields

```
content_type=models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
posted_wall = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

And I don't get why posted_wall is None below..

```
(Pdb) p thread.content_type
p thread.content_type
<ContentType: foo>
(Pdb) p thread.object_id
p thread.object_id
18
(Pdb) p thread.posted_wall
p thread.posted_wall
None
(Pdb)
```

I noticed you can't use genericForeginKey field when filtering on queryset.
Are there other cases where I shouldn't try to access GenericForeignKey field?

**EDIT**

The object access is done in dehydrate_something in tastypie.
I guess the bundle.obj is not fully populated in dehydrate_FOO .

Comment: how are you setting it?

Comment: using tastypie's obj_create function. your question made me think something.. I'm updating the question

Comment: by [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey) i guess you should set the `posted_wall`, and then `content_type` and  `object_id` will be set automaticaly